# Return const char* from a function combining two string literals

Tags: c++, string-literals

I have an old-style interface function, and after some refactoring, I need to return its original `const char*` pointer, which shouldn't be deleted.

The function looks like this:

```
const char* func()
{
    ...
    return "Some string literal that contains some value to be moved out: VALUE";
}
```

I need to move the VALUE outside and use it in the return statement like this(combine 2 strings):

```
constexpr auto MY_VALUE = "VALUE";

const char* func()
{
    ...
    static const std::string msg = "Some string literal that contains some value to be moved out: " + MY_VALUE;
    return msg.c_str();
}
```

But I don't like this static variable.

Is there another better approach to combine two known at the compile time string literals?

Comment: `const char *` points to a string that is in some memory somewhere ... you cannot avoid the issue of lifetime management for that memory

Comment: The compiler will concatenate adjacent string literals, but not if one of them is assigned to a variable. Maybe you could just ditch the `MY_VALUE` variable or (heaven forbid!) replace it with a macro.

Comment: Does the receiver of this result want to `free()` it? Or can it be made to do so?

Comment: why do you not like the static variable? why do you think the string literal would be better?

Comment: @bitmask Users of this function shouldn't delete/free its result.

Comment: @john This is a refactoring project. MY_VALUE is used over the system in a few places. That's why I need to create its single instance.

Comment: I think the static **const** variable is fine. Everything it depends on is a compile-time constant and so the value will not change.

Comment: @bitmask Yes, I'm just trying to find the best possible solution. It seems that something will have to be sacrificed for the sake of the result.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach, not necessary better, with `#define`:

```
#define MY_VALUE "VALUE"

const char* func()
{
    return "Some string literal that contains some value to be moved out: " MY_VALUE;
}
```